# Getting 502 response upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream on elastic beanstalk using Nginx + puma

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ruby, elastic-beanstalk

I'm getting this error in log files. it happens when a person reloads page many times. other than that website is working fine. I'm using elastic beanstalk with Nginx + Puma.

`upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.XX.XX.XX, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/", host: "example.com"`

Also, I've added these configurations for the Nginx but these configurations didn't fix the problem.

```
proxy_connect_timeout 300;
proxy_read_timeout 300;
```

Comment: Check your application's log. This is almost always a problem with your web application code.

Comment: I've checked the web server and application logs. but there is no error logs or issue.

Comment: Also if it was an issue with the application then we should get an error on all requests.